# EXC_BAD_ACCESS AFNetworking in GET:parameters:success:failure

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, kiwi

I'm testing some code that performs some network operations. I'm using Kiwi and OHHTTPStubs libraries.

Currently i have one clase that holds all the responsibilities for performing requests, i'm
using the Singleton pattern. This object holds a reference to an AFHTTPRequestOperationManager where i build my requests.

Here is the stack trace when the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs.

[image]

UPDATE:

This is the place where it crashes in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

    return operation;
}
```

Line:

```
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Can you paste code here so that we can identify in which api is crashing

Comment: I just added more information, thanks.

Comment: Did you check what data you are getting inside request??

Comment: It builds the correct request. I just noticed that it worked at least ones. I'm having some random success cases.

Comment: ya thats what whenever it is failure you are adding in the operatioqueue and then its crashing

Comment: So don't add in the operationqueue whenever it gets failed

Comment: I don't have control when it fails. The execution of all the test suit ends when the SIGSEGV is triggered.

Comment: Basically this crash SIGSEGV indicates that your variable has been released and your code is trying to access its reference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39241/discussion-between-bilby91-and-hussain-shabbir)